# css ul and li - multiple spans in each li and how to line up the spans vertically

Tags: html, css, html-lists, vertical-alignment

i have a list:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="first">the dog jumped over the fox</span>
        <span class="second">1</span>
        <span class="third">Edit</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="first">cat and mouse</span>
        <span class="second">1</span>
        <span class="third">Edit</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="first">doggie</span>
        <span class="second">1</span>
        <span class="third">View report</span>
    </li>        
</ul>
```

and i want to set the width of the first `<span>` in each `<li>` to be equal to the one with the longest text. in this case, the longest text is "the dog jumped over the fox" so i want all the other `<span class="first">`s to match it. i also want to apply the same logic to any additional `<span>`s within the `<li>`.  basically, all the `<span class="first">` have the same length, all the `<span class="second">` have the same length, and all the `<span class="third">` have the same length.  here's what i want to achieve:

```
-------------------------------------------
the dog jumped over the fox |1|Edit       |
-------------------------------------------
cat and mouse               |1|Edit       |
-------------------------------------------
doggie                      |1|View report|
-------------------------------------------
```

thanks!

Comment: you want to use it in ul only? or can you use it in table also? because your requirement similar with table concept?

Comment: this is pretty much an ideal scenario for the use of `table` and `tr`,`td` functionality

Comment: this is in the left hand nav, and it is using `<ul>`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apply CSS like below.

```
 ul{display:table; width:100%; padding:0;}
 li{display:table-row;}
 li span{display:table-cell; text-align:left;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/e3pcb69z/)

Answer (score 1):

What about using `<table>`?

[See this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/L6dhc2dw/)

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>the dog jumped over the fox</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Edit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>cat and mouse</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Edit</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>doggie</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>View report</td>
    </tr>        
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the li to display: block; and float at least the first span, then give it a certain width. Haven't tested for crossbrowser compatibility, but it should work. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fdhu0w07/

```
`
ul {
    display: block;
}
ul li {
    display: block;
}

ul li span {
    display: inline-block;
}

ul > li > span:first-of-type{
    float: left;
    width: 220px;
}`
```

Comment: The width of the spans may have to be dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Put your list in a table in your html.

```
<table>

<ul>
  <li>
    <span class="first">the dog jumped over the fox</span>
    <span class="second">1</span>
    <span class="third">Edit</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="first">cat and mouse</span>
    <span class="second">1</span>
    <span class="third">Edit</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="first">doggie</span>
    <span class="second">1</span>
    <span class="third">View report</span>
  </li>        
  </ul>

</table>
```

Then in your CSS

```
table{
table-layout: fixed;
width: 300px;
}
```

The Pixel Width can be up to you!

Good Luck!